# my KML file is not working on Javascript code

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

When I try to add my file 'myFile.kml' that I exported from google maps, it won't show any path to my map, while the example from google 'http://googlemaps.github.io/js-v2-samples/ggeoxml/cta.kml' does work fine ?
Any idea of what am I missing here.

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #map {
            height:100%
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body >


    <div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my JS code:

```
    var map;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: 42.658324, lng: 21.163883},
            zoom: 10
        });
        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: 'myFile.kml',
            map: map
        });

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to access your file from localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to load KML file from localhost or local file system.

If so, basically you have two choices:

- place the KML file on a *public server* where google server 
  can get to, since parsing of KML and rendering is done by 
  Google servers
- utilize [geoxml3 library](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) which allows you to load KML file and
  parse it *hosted on localhost* (see below example)

**Example**

The example demonstrates how to load and parse KML file from localhost using [geoxml3 library](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/):

```
var map;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624 },
        zoom: 10
    });


    var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({ map: map });
    myParser.parse('cta.kml');
}
```

In HTML file add a reference to [geoxml3 library](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/), for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://geoxml3.googlecode.com/svn/branches/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vd8gDGZdMaQbD8VyPzJs?p=preview)